# How to set constrain on GAMs to analyze cell growth curve?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

**Background:** I am trying to understand basics of Generalized Additive models (GAMs) in order to analyze growth curve in my experiment.

**Goal:** I am using `mgcv` package in R. In my first step (before adding any complexity) I'm simply trying to look at cell growth as a function of time.

**Problem:** The problem is that the value of response can't be lower than the first data point. I understand I'm setting k to the maximum and more data points improves the model.

**Question:** Is there anyway to set up a constrain in a way that yhat does not fall below a certain threshold?

**Example:** Here is a small example, cell density (y) between time 0 and day 2 cannot be lower than the initial value which is 500000.

```r
library(mgcv)
val <- c(500000,60600000,59700000,51600000,45300000,57800000,54600000,447500000,432500000,430000000,422500000,455000000,428000000,563200000,448800000,463467000,464933000,500000000,518000000,615700000,855400000,667400000,672100000,702650000,712650000,676800000,733200000,680000000,705000000,698750000,689750000)
tm <- c(0,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6)
dat <- data.frame(tm,val); dat

mod <- gam(val ~ s(tm, k = 6), data = dat)

plot(mod, residuals = T, pch = 1,
     shift = coef(mod)[1])
```

[image]

Using `scam` package kinda satisfies the constrain but it seems like an overfit:

```r
scamod <- scam(val ~ s(tm, k=9, bs = "mpi", m = 1), data = dat)

plot(scamod, residuals = T, pch = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to inform the model that negative values are not allows by choosing an appropriate response distribution. The default in `gam()` is to assume the response is conditionally distributed Gaussian (Normal) and that allows for negative values of the response and hence you get odd fits for data like this.

Fitting would be improved by taking logs of the `val` variable and modelling that or using a family that doesn't allow negative values, such as the `Gamma` or `tw` families.

For example, you seem to get a better fit if you use:

```
mod <- gam(val ~ s(tm, k = 6), data = dat, family = tw())
```

which for your data produces

```
> summary(mod)

Family: Tweedie(p=1.765) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
val ~ s(tm, k = 6)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 19.48148    0.01541    1264   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
       edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(tm) 4.97      5 919.7  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.972   Deviance explained = 99.3%
-REML =  587.1  Scale est. = 0.6521    n = 31
```

and

[image]

And note that I used

```
plot(mod, residuals = TRUE, pch = 1)
```

to generate the plot as fiddling with the intercept in general (not here, for complex non-Gaussian models) is a bit scary; better to `predict()` on the response scale and add on the data.

I should also note that you might want to combine this idea with the monotonic constraint of @usεr11852 (fro the comments)

Comment: Thanks, I understood much more but still I'm unable to satisfy my goal, I'm going to edit the question.